# MySQL get time between HH:MM

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I got the following query that shows restaurants that are open between "mon_o" and "mon_c"

```
  SELECT name FROM `restaurants` WHERE "18:00" BETWEEN mon_o AND mon_c
```

This works as it should, but I want to extend the opening times for the restaurants so mon_c *(That means Monday closing)* can be past 24:00.
So for example, a restaurants open between 15:00 and 04:00 will not be returned with my query above because 04:00 is not counted as the next day, it's counted as the same day as mon_o *(Monday opening time)*.

How can I edit my query so a restaurant that is open from 17:00 and 02:00 can be returned?

Help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution is just assuming that it's a past-midnight closing hour if `mon_c` is smaller than `mon_o`:

```
SELECT name FROM `restaurants` 
WHERE (mon_o < mon_c AND "18:00" BETWEEN mon_o AND mon_c)
   OR (mon_o > mon_c AND ("18:00" > mon_o OR "18:00" < mon_c))
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks so much, I'll accept your answer in 4 minutes!

Answer (score 1):

So really to have two scenarios that you need to capture in your query.

Scenario #1 - closing time is < 23:59

In this scenario mon_c (or whatever day) would always be > mon_o, so your current where clause will work as is

Scenario #2 - closing time is > 23:59
 In this scenario mon_c would always be < mon_o, so this is what you need to solve.

You can do this by building building two parts to your WHERE clause, one to cover each scenario.

```
WHERE
(
  mon_c > mon_0
  AND
  ? BETWEEN mon_o AND mon_c
) /* scenario #1 */
OR
(
  mon_c < mon_o
  AND
  (
    ? > mon_o
    OR
    ? < mon_c
  )
) /* scenario #2 */
```